# Kubernetes CockroachDB unable to access cluster externally

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, cockroachdb

I installed cockroachdb via operator therefore used a kind: crdbcluster to spin up the cluster. Also using a metallb as loadbalancer.

I'm trying to access a cockroachdb externally by exposing an ingress according to the documentation here (at the very bottom):
https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/configure-cockroachdb-kubernetes.html

I did everything that was in the guide, enabled tcp in haproxy (my IC) and the haproxy service correctly listens on tcp 26257.

`helm-chart-haproxy-ingress   LoadBalancer   10.223.153.11   172.20.15.81`   80:31658/TCP,443:31802/TCP,26257:31516/TCP

Provisioned the record A on my dns server and it works since it gives me error 404.
But then I'm not able to provision an ip address to the ingress spinned up by cockroachdb.

Is it correct? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I see you posted about this issue here [Kubernetes: Haproxy ingress isn't taking on any addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76659547/kubernetes-haproxy-ingress-isnt-taking-on-any-addresses)

And that you commented that the issue was resolved with the metallb custom resource.

Are you still experiencing trouble?

Comment: It looks like the issue is haproxy, if you do the exact same thing using nginx it works..